# VBA Conditional formatting based on dynamic criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that I was originally going to manually enter this formula and adapt to suit the cell: =AND(Date(eg.AE22)>=StartDate(eg.G25),Date(same as before)<=EndDate(eg.I25)) *This is the formula that was going into Cell AE25.*
For all the cells in that row that were for that day(eg.26-Oct) would have the exact same formula. Then for then next day(27-Oct) I was going to have to change the Date(from AE22 to AI22) so that formula would be correct.
Finally I would set the condition formatting to highlight it if it was True and not if it was False.
I wanted to see if I was able to do this all by VBA so that it automatically updates if there is any changes on worksheet. I'm sure it can be done but I have been able to find anything that can help me.
The purpose of the worksheet is to create a dynamic production schedule in a gantlet chart view.

#### Screen shot of the worksheet

[image: Screen shot of the worksheet]

Let me know if you require any more information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the conditional formatting to apply to different columns, based on today's date?

Comment: Were you able to see my screen shot?

Comment: Yes, but I confess I wasn't 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish.  I notionally get it (I was a production scheduler in a former life, believe it or not), but I'm not sure what the spreadsheet looks like on 10/26 vs 10/27.  Can you mock that up?  It doesn't need to be fancy, just demonstrate the before and after.

Comment: In Columns A to I, I have Jobs/Projects and their details such as Start Date(column G) and End Date(column I). Then along the top from Column AE to KB I have Dates starting from Todays date and onwards. I want to use conditional formatting in VBA to color the cells between the Start and End dates for each job so that it creates a Gantt Chart look. Hope this helps?

Comment: I'll try to mock it up.

Comment: I think I get it now...

Comment: **26/10/2016**      **27/10/2016** **Job**  **Name**     **Start**     **End**                                               J2345    Edward St   26/10/16   27/10/16        CC                         CC  J2225    Nova St       27/10/16   28/10/16        NC                         CC

Comment: NC Stands for a Conditionally Non-Colored cell and CC Stands for a Conditionally Colored cell. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Explanation: A job(for example J1125) begins on the 26th Oct and ends on the 27th Oct. The columns with those dates will be colored. But for a job that is not to be worked on on those dates will remain colorless.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely crude, but hopefully it gives you the idea.  This example colors the cells yellow:

```
Sub FormatGantt()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim fromDate, toDate, colDate As Date
  Dim row, col As Integer

  For row = 25 To 29
    fromDate = Cells(row, 7).Value2
    toDate = Cells(row, 9).Value2

    For col = 31 To 50 Step 4
      colDate = Cells(22, col).Value2
      If colDate >= fromDate And colDate <= toDate Then
        Range(Cells(row, col), Cells(row, col + 3)).Interior.Color = 65535

      End If
    Next col

  Next row


End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of this:

[image]

This does it against a very narrow range.  To accomplish what you are seeking to do, when any change is made, you want to fire the Worksheet_Change event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx), detect what cell(s) we changed and apply the formatting below accordingly.

Comment: That's great @Hambone. However it is highlighting just one row and it is the entire row. I am needing only the cells in the row,for each job/row, where the column is within the start to end date. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you upload a sample to Dropbox (or whatever)?

Comment: How am I best to share it from dropbox?

Comment: Does this work? https://www.dropbox.com/s/lx0xo8eywuz01uq/Product%20Schedule.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Sorry I didn't give you the one with the macro in it. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgv9u17acqgr89f/Product%20Schedule.xlsm?dl=0    - The Yellow is what the macro does and the green is what I would like it to look like. I have changed it slightly so that it goes to Last Row and to Column 288 which is what I want.